# Selenium - how to use AND condition with find_element_by_xpath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

[image: inspector]

Hi. Could you help me with create a condition which allows to filter element that for example contains "Cutout" AND "Grey"? I am stuck with it for 3 hours.

> //*[contains(text(),'Cutout') and ?]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

success with:

```
//div[contains(h1, 'Cutout') and p='Red']
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the OR condition for that and put it in a list:

```
 links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(text,'Cutout') or contains(text,'Grey')]")
```

Note: You have to loop through the list to perform any actions.